# Cannot get pointers result

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int v=10;
    char *p=&v;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++,p++)
    {
        ++(*p);
        printf("%d",v);
    }
}
```

Output

```
11
267
65803
16843019
16843019
16843019
```

I am not getting how output came like this please explain

Comment: Hi. It's not clear what programming language this is actually written in. Please clarify.

Comment: First of all, don't use an editor which auto-capitalize "sentences". Secondly, please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please edit your question to include the *expected* output as well, and your own thoughts about the actual result. Lastly, don't spam with irrelevant tags.

Comment: `char *p=&v;` is a type error.

Comment: `int` doesn't have 10 bytes so you can't do this. What happens if you try it still is anyone's guess.

Comment: @melpomene `char*`s are special, the cousin of `void*`, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume, that an expected behavior is to get variable `v` incremented 10 times using pointer.

If that's correct, you have two mistakes:

1. Type of pointer should be the same with the data you're pointing. If you're pointing at `int` variable, you should use `int *` pointer.
2. In the `for` loop condition: at each iteration you're incrementing both `i` and `p` (`i++,p++`).
   When you're incrementing pointer, it moves to the next memory cell (in simple words, actually it's a bit complicated).
   If you want to work with variable `v` only, you should not modify the pointer itself, only the variable it refers to.
   Thus, if you'll remove `p++` part , you'll get `11, 12, 13, ...` as a result.

Why it shows such a weird results now? Just because at each iteration you're changing pointer (thus it refers to other memory cell). Memory that pointer refers to after increment may contain random data, which we are able to see. However, such an approach contains undefined behavior, and results may vary. It may even end with termination of the program.

However, it's indeed not clear what behavior are you expecting to get, and if you'll clarify that more, I guess community will be able to help you more.

Comment: The result also depends on endianess.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. And even may be altered by `CHAR_BIT` constant. But I guess such details are a bit too high-level for a beginner's question, so I tried to simplify answer as much as possible and left only simple theses.

Comment: On the contrary, the endianess argument is the reason why we shouldn't teach newbies to iterate over bytes on an integer using pointer arithmetic. Instead use bit shifts. From the newbie's point of view, they need to know that their source of learning is crap. Although `void main()` alone is enough to tell as much.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not getting how output came like this please explain

First let's make some minor changes to your code and print the values in hex:

```
int main() {
  int v = 10;
  char *p = (char*)&v;
  int i;
  printf("%8d (0x%08x)\n", v, v);
  for(i=0; i<sizeof(i); i++, p++)
  {
    ++(*p);
    printf("%8d (0x%08x)\n", v, v);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
      10 (0x0000000a)
      11 (0x0000000b)
     267 (0x0000010b)
   65803 (0x0001010b)
16843019 (0x0101010b)
```

So what happens here is that the `int` is four bytes - consequently I get 4 values printed by the loop (plus the print before the loop).

Since `p` is a char pointer and my system is little endian, `p` will first point to the LSB (least significant byte) of the integer, i.e. "0a", and increment that byte to "0b".

When `p` is incremented by `p++` it will point to the next byte, i.e. "00" and increment that byte to "01". So now the integer holds "0000010b" (267 decimal). This step is repeated twice so that the integer first become "0001010b" (65803 decimal) and then "0101010b" (16843019 decimal).

In memory it looks like:

```
After initialization: 0a 00 00 00
                      ^
                      |
                      p

After loop 1:         0b 00 00 00
                         ^
                         |
                         p

After loop 2:         0b 01 00 00
                            ^
                            |
                            p

After loop 2:         0b 01 01 00
                               ^
                               |
                               p

After loop 4:         0b 01 01 01
                                  ^
                                  |
                                  p
```

BTW: Notice that the standard gives no guarantees about this behavior. Updating bytes inside an integer using a char pointer is not well defined by the standard.